# Having to press Shift along with CTRL A

Tags: c#

TO start, I have looked extensively at the answers and haven't found a method.

I have a text box that gets ctl+A to select all.
I also have a list box that traps the kb to select all items.

The listbox is my issue.

```
if(e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A  )
```

and also

```
if(e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString().ToLower() == "a"  )
```

are requiring ctl + shift + a, as the keys.A is always uppercase, even when I lowercase it. If I don't press shift, it starts cycling through the items that start with "a".
Using keypress to grab the keys, I can't find the char for the control key anywhere. Using key up and down to flag control: if I press control, keypress event stops firing.

All I want to do is have ctl + lowercase a = The code that selects all of the items in the listbox.

This cannot be that hard, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am so embarrassed, but I will leave this here for anyone else who has this issue. Literally the easiest and fastest fix I managed to overlook for many weeks and many clumps of hair...

I randomly started changing the listbox properties to see if anything helped. This was the result of us needing it in "multi Extended, rather than "MultiSimple" as we shift and select a range of files to alter, but also often need to quickly select all with standard(er) Quick keys.
I added this to the keydown event just prior to checking against selectall...

```
 if(e.Shift)
            {
                FinalNameList.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
            }
            else{
                FinalNameList.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
            }
```